# How to override a default background of an icon with a background color that a user selects?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, partials

I have an icon and it's default color is white with a blue background around it. This default background color remains as is, if the user doesn't choose a background color.  However, if the user does choose a new background color for eg:(here are their options: pink, gray, orange) the default background color should be overridden with the new color that the user chooses. 
The user will make their background color selection through a content management system that has the `'iconBackground'` box in which the user will choose the color they want.

My questions is how can I override the default background color(blue), when the user makes a selection of background color? Here is the code that has  razor and css: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/bjhvpf7q/9/ . What I have tried is, first validate that  `myIcon` and `iconBackground` fields are not empty. If they are not empty, then output their values, however, I am not sure how to override the default background color with the value of  `iconBackground` which has the new background color.

Comment: By `icon` i would assume you have a `*.png` file with a `transparent` background. If so, wrap the icon around a container(*div/span/any other wrapper*) and change that wrapper's background colour. And if not then you will not be able to perform what you are trying to achieve(*easily*).

Comment: conditionality change the class of the element and have each class as as style rule.

Comment: @vikscool, the icon is an svg font awesome icon. https://fontawesome.com/icons/home-lg?style=solid

Comment: Hi @Vince, I am not following your steps. Could you please demo or provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet illustrated the logic, you can just remove the select and replace the `@iconBackground` variable with the css class name

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#colorSelect');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  var icon = document.querySelector('.tinyicon');
  var newClass = event.target.value;
  icon.className = "tinyicon "+newClass;
});
```

```css
.tinyicon {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 6px;
}
    
.default{
  background: blue;
}

.green{
  background: green;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span><i title="Icon" class="tinyicon default"></i> This is my content</span>
<select id="colorSelect">
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```